# gcloud CLI: use IPv4 only

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sql, ipv6, ipv4

Is there a way to configure or flag the gcloud CLI to connect via IPv4 only?

Trying to connect to a Cloud SQL v2 instance fails (`gcloud sql connect`), because they do not support IPv6:

```
$ gcloud sql connect # ... + DB details ...

WARNING: If you're connecting from an IPv6 address, or are constrained by certain organization policies (restrictPublicIP, restrictAuthorizedNetworks), consider running the beta version of this command by connecting through the Cloud SQL proxy: gcloud beta sql connect
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.connect) HTTPError 400: Invalid request: Invalid flag for instance role: CloudSQL Second Generation doesn't support IPv6 networks/subnets
```

I can connect to the instance (with the same command) after disabling IPv6 in my computer's network settings, but how can I specify this just for the gcloud CLI?

Comment: There is no direct flag in the CLI to configure IPv4 only. Check this [Proxy configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings#proxy_configuration). you can use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-auth-proxy) to connect to your instance this will handle  connectivity issues